# Inserting a value into a A HREF through PHP

Tags: php, sql, arrays, tags, row

Sorry if this question has been asked before but I've looked through all the questions on here but I still can't quite grasp how to complete my task.

```
require_once 'database/connect.php';
$sql = <<<SQL
    SELECT *
    FROM `blog_posts`
SQL;
if(!$result = $db->query($sql)){
    die('There was an error running the query [' . $db->error . ']');
}
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    echo "<a href=''>".$row['postTitle']."</a>";
    echo $row['postDesc'];
    echo $row['postDate'];
}
$db->close();
```

I am trying to then, in the  tag, post: 'blog/viewpost.php?=POST_ID' so for every one that is echoed it'll already have the post ID in the link. Any ideas? I thought it would be best to make postID a variable and insert it that way. I'm having no luck though. Maybe I'm just tired but I'm not sure.

Sorry if it is an easy fix.

Comment: Hi there. We don't mark post titles as 'solved' here - we either accept an answer, or write our own, and accept that. Would you do one of those two? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    echo "<a href='blog/viewpost.php?post=" . $row['postID'] . "'>".$row['postTitle']."</a>";
    echo $row['postDesc'];
    echo $row['postDate'];
}
```

Just add your ID directly into the href. You possibly need to change the name of the selected field ('postID') for that.

**edit**

You can then access the post ID via `$_GET['post']`.

Comment: You might want to add a key to the ID in the url to make retrieving it a bit easier later on.

Comment: Thanks @jeroen, adjusted it.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed. Line 10.

Replace 'id' with your db row name.

```
require_once 'database/connect.php';
$sql = <<<SQL
    SELECT *
    FROM `blog_posts`
SQL;
if(!$result = $db->query($sql)){
    die('There was an error running the query [' . $db->error . ']');
}
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    echo "<a href='/blog/viewpost.php?=".$row['id']."'>".$row['postTitle']."</a>";
    echo $row['postDesc'];
    echo $row['postDate'];
}
$db->close();
```

Comment: You're missing quotations in the `href` attribute

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
define(LINK_HTML, '<a href="blog/viewpost.php?=%d">%s</a>');

...
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
    echo sprintf(LINK_HTML, $row['postID'], $row['postTitle']);
    echo $row['postDesc'];
    echo $row['postDate'];
}
...
```

with `postID` and the URL adapted to your needs?